Google Client API: Uncaught TypeError: Argument must be an instance of RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload
Data sources
1)
I use this releas https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases of google client api library - for  php 7.4
https://prnt.sc/l-WHG_rzCgGt - this one
2)
And use this samples library https://github.com/googleads/googleads-shopping-samples/tree/main/php to make some requests to my Google Shopping (Google Merchant) account.
My problen IS:
When I try to call such function in my script.php file, it trow the error.
public function get_info($accountId) {     $status = $this->session->service->merchantsupport->renderaccountissues(         $this->session->merchantId, '{ "contentOption": "CONTENT_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED" }'); return $status;   }
The error is:
Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Google\Service\ShoppingContent\Resource\Merchantsupport::renderaccountissues() must be an instance of Google\Service\ShoppingContent\RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload, string given, called in /home/tatam0/tadam/test/php_merchant_api/AccountstatusesSample.php on line 65 and defined in /home/tatam0/tadam/test/php_merchant_api/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/ShoppingContent/Resource/Merchantsupport.php:54
Here is documentation on this funtcion renderaccountissues()
https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/reference/rest/v2.1/merchantsupport/renderaccountissues
https://prnt.sc/iKGzL5HCHGTx - I did as it says
What does mean "must be an instance of RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload"? I do not understand, how can I change my php-code to make this funnction work correctly?
I tried to make an object or an array from this '{ "contentOption": "CONTENT_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED" }', but it does not help.

It means exactly what it says - you need to pass an instance of the RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload class as second parameter. Not a string containing JSON, and not any arbitrary object. Which of the two libraries you mentioned is supposed to contain this class, I can't tell right now - maybe do a search over your whole project, and see if you can find its definition. "Here is documentation on this funtcion renderaccountissues()" - please not that that is not documentation for the specific SDK you are using, but only the documentation of the API endpoint itself.

@CBroe can you show a php code example, how i can make an instance of the RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload class?
`namespace Google\Service\ShoppingContent;
class RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload extends \Google\Model
{
/**

@var string
*/
public $contentOption;

/**

@param string
/
public function setContentOption($contentOption)
{
$this->contentOption = $contentOption;
}
/*
@return string
*/
public function getContentOption()
{
return $this->contentOption;
}
}`

https://prnt.sc/U-RGCTKuK9gu

Create a new instance, and then call the setContentOption option, to explicitly set the value CONTENT_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED ...

I tried to do this from the very beginning. But I don’t understand how to correctly set the value using the setContentOption option. I do it like this use Google\Service\ShoppingContent\RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload; $payload = new RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload(); $var = $payload->setContentOption('CONTENT_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED'); 
But it returns NULL.
I suspect my problem is that I can't connect the class correctly. I thought that those people who worked with these google-client-php-api classes would tell me something specific.

Who said the setter method had to return anything? Not every class implements method chaining. $var is superfluous, and $payload is what you should now pass as parameter in the renderaccountissues call.

@CBroe thanks for the advice. It really worked as you recommended. But now the following question arose: how can I pass the value I need PRE_RENDERED_HTML to this instance of the class? Like it says
I tried like this $payload->setContentOption('PRE_RENDERED_HTML'); But it did not help. The response from the server arrives in the default format, i.e. CONTENT_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED

What does the code of the setContentOption method look like? Maybe you need to pass in some constant defined by the class, instead of a string value.

@CBroe How this method look like you can see in it's own file RenderAccountIssuesRequestPayload.php. Also there you can find a Merchantsupport.php file with function renderaccountissues(), which processes the value of the $payload parameter.
I tried to pass constant PRE_RENDERED_HTML like this  $payload->setContentOption(PRE_RENDERED_HTML); But the response from the server arrives in the same default format (not in RENDERED HTML as I expected)...
